# Find out which user created local incoming TCP connection inside of application

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, udp, uid

On Linux, it's possible to filter packets originating on localhost based on the user or group that created them, i.e. who owns the socket:

```
iptables ... -m owner --uid-owner $USER --gid-owner $GROUP -p tcp ...
```

But I want to approach it from the *point of view of the program*, running on localhost and written in C, *receiving* the packets: I bound to some port, and here comes a new TCP connection / UDP packets. How to find out who sent that?

Answer (score 2):

Strange use-case, but hey, perhaps something like this could work - but it aint pretty:

1. Get inode number for the fd returned by `accept` using `fstat`.
2. Read `/proc/self/net/tcp`
3. Parse and find the row matching the inode number.
4. Use the uid of that row.

Comment: I need the GID, but this only lists the UID. "Oh yeah, we're boned." How about that netlink thing all the kids seem to use?

Comment: I guess you should be able to look it up using `getpwuid`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You get the remote IP address and port. That's it.